# How to find the coefficient of a variable in the expansion of a product of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials

I have trouble finding the coefficient of a variable in: $(1 + x)(2 + x^2)(3 + x^3)(4 + x^4)(5 + x^5)$.

Say we have to find the coefficient of $x^7$. By brute-forcing we can expand the products and find the coefficient. But that does not seem too practical.

My first take to find it, is to consider what products yield $x^7$? We have $(x^2, x^5), (x^3, x^4), (x, x^2, x^4)$. And this is the part where I get stuck. We can see the coefficients of the variables depends on the numbers $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)$ or constants inside each term. Then it would only make sense to just expand all the products.

My question is, is there any practical way to find the coefficient of $x^7$ without expanding the products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You counted twice the terms. $(x^2x^5)$ is the same as $(x^5 x^2)$. You can also have $(x, x^2, x^4)$. The idea is that you need to take one term from each parenthesis. So the three cases you care about is taking

1. $x^5$ from the last one, $x^2$ from the second. Then you need to take $1$, $3$, and $4$ from the other, so this will yield $12x^7$.
2. Take $x^3$ and $x^4$, so the constant terms are $1, 2, 5$. This yields $10x^7$
3. Take $x,x^2,x^4$, together with $3$ and $5$, so you get $15x^7$.

Total for the coefficients of $x^7$ is $12+10+15=37$.

If you expand everything, you will need to calculate all 16 terms.

Comment: Equivalently, $5!\cdot(\frac1{2\cdot5}+\frac1{3\cdot4}+\frac1{1\cdot2\cdot4})=37$ where each denominator is the product of allowable partitions of $7$ already identified by the OP. +1